# SQL Server 2008 DateTime range query

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2008

I have a table called `Users`：

| CreateTime | UserName |
| --- | --- |
| 2012-08-30 14:23:12:000 | zhang |
| 2012-08-30 15:11:13:000 | li |
| 2012-08-30 16:32:22:000 | wang |
| 2012-08-31 11:23:12:000 | steven |
| 2012-08-31 12:05:14:000 | zhao |
| 2012-08-31 08:23:12:000 | ddd |

and a query:

```
select UserName 
from Users  
where CreateTime >= '2012-08-30' and CreateTime <= '2012-08-31'
```

So, the results should be 6 rows, but it does not.

How to solve this?

Using SQL Server `Convert` function `CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), CreateTime, 121)`?

Comment: your CreateTime column is a dateTime column? And you should use a datetype in your WHERE clause aswell (currently you use a string, mostly the reason why it is not working). Edit: use something like CAST('01-JAN-2009' AS DATETIME)

Comment: Incorrect. Strings are perfectly fine representations of dates/times in ANSI SQL. His query is only about three characters wrong, and there are multiple copies of the solution below.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is not showing 6 rows because `2012-08-31` is received by the interpreter as `2012-08-31 00:00:00 AM`. Since you want to see data up to and including the 31st, you can either ***explicitly*** mention the time or query the next day's date.

**Example Using the Next Day's Date**

```
SELECT UserName 
FROM Users  
WHERE CreateTime >= '2012-08-30' AND CreateTime < '2012-09-01'
```

**Example with Time Explicitly Mentioned**

```
SELECT UserName 
FROM Users  
WHERE CreateTime >= '2012-08-30 00:00:00' AND CreateTime < '2012-09-31 23:59:59'
```

Comment: in your second query, you should use <= instead of < to include the last second of the day: `... and CreateTime <= '2012-09-31 23:59:59' `

Answer (score 16):

All you need is to [`CAST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) your `CreateTime` from `Datetime` to `Date` like this:

```
SELECT  UserName FROM Users 
WHERE CAST(CreateTime as date)>='2012-08-30' 
AND CAST(CreateTime as date)<= '2012-08-31';
```

You can also use `BETWEEN` instead of `<=` and `>=` like this:

```
SELECT  UserName FROM Users 
WHERE CAST(CreateTime as date) BETWEEN 
'2012-08-30' AND '2012-08-31';
```

##### [*See this SQLFiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/03642/1)

Comment: Since the `CreateTime` column is a `DATETIME` column, I would probably use `CAST(CreateTime AS DATE)` instead - no need to specify a string format / style for the conversion....

Comment: @marc_s You are right. We should use `CAST` instead of `CONVERT` when column datatype is `DATETIME`. Updated the answer.

Comment: @hims056: If you use a CAST on the database's CreateTime value like that, it messes with the indexes so your query will run slowly.

Answer (score 3):

The basic problem is that, when you simply enter a date, SQL Server interprets that date as midnight on that date.  So, when you ask for '2012-08-31', it really means '2012-08-31 12:00AM'.

The best solution is to go one day beyond the day you want and use less than, rather than less than or equal.

```
select  UserName from  Users  where CreateTime>='2012-08-30' and CreateTime < '2012-09-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select  UserName 
from  Users  
where CreateTime>='2012-08-30' and CreateTime<'2012-09-01'
```

Comment: Less than or equal in the second condition will go too far.  It needs to be less than only.

Comment: Oh, forgot to delete that sign.

Answer (score 0):

`CreateTime<='2012-08-31'` is never true for last three dates, as their time stamps are after midnight. `2012-08-31` is short for `2012-08-31 00:00:00`, so only the first three lines are returned.

You should always include a timestamp - also: using `BETWEEN` as suggested in the other answers is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  UserName from  Users  where CreateTime>='2012-08-30' and CreateTime < '2012-09-01'
```

Comment: Please format your source code properly and do not just copy other people's answers.

Comment: HI  Thorsten Dittmar  how do i do this

Comment: Mostly by deleting the answer, at this point.  There are multiple copies of the correct solution here already.  In the future, to format code properly, select the code that you have typed in the form and click the button that looks like two curly braces ( { } ).  This will indent the text, which tells StackOverflow to format it as code in the page.

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like below:

```
SELECT UserName 
 FROM Users 
WHERE DATEDIFF(d, '2012-08-30', CreateTime) >= 0 
  AND DATEDIFF(d, @ToDate, '2012-09-01') <=0
```

You will not need to pass hours and minutes with this query.